# File scheme to Document scheme Uri

Tags: android, uri, storage-access-framework

I'm looking to do the opposite of what one would expect.  I'd like to go from a file scheme (file://) to a document scheme (content://...externalstorage...).  The reason for this is that UriPermission is a form of tree document uri.  So to confirm you have a permission at or higher than the current file you're interested in you'd ideally want to check against the UriPermission, which would mean you'd need to somehow convert the file path to the document uri with it's appropriate "rootId".  For example:

File:

`file:///storage/sdcard1/_WriteTest/file.ext`

Document Version:

`content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/0000-0000%3A_WriteTest/document/0000-0000%3A_WriteTest%2Ffile.ext`

Permission at root:

`content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/0000-0000%3A_WriteTest`

So the document version is fairly easy to correlate with by comparing treeId to documentId, but the critical thing is to correlate `/storage/sdcard1` to `0000-0000` in the file case.

Any idea if that's possible?

Comment: It certainly is not possible in any reliable fashion. Device manufacturers, custom ROM developers, and Google themselves are welcome to change the implementation of this provider whenever they want to. This includes changing the `Uri`. Today, the `Uri` might be `content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/0000-0000%3A_WriteTest/document/0000-0000%3A_WriteTest%2Ffile.ext`. Tomorrow, the `Uri` might be `content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/9ae066255e3177c2fc83681fd1cb488112a0eb50`. A `Uri` from a third-party source should be treated as an opaque handle, nothing more.

Comment: For one, they must retain support for the current format or break all apps relying on the UriPermission they so haphazardly implemented with any future Android update.

For two, given the restrictions of the SAF and Document API, and the flaws in `DocumentFile`, the only real way to ensure you have write access is to check for a permission up the tree.  Hence this is an entirely necessary exercise, whether it's ideal or not is irrelevant given that we HAVE to do it, or risk all sorts of horrors relying on the broken getParents/canRead/canWrite of DocumentFile.

Comment: If you dig down into the nitty gritty of `DocumentsContract` it's fair to say they will not change from an hierarchical tree format.  If you rely on the `DocumentsContract` methods to get your Ids one should hope that functionality would be retained.  However the actual id assigned a given SAF root and it's file counterpart (at least on non-transient storage) would be necessary to relate these uris.

Comment: "For one..." -- no, they just need to honor existing legacy `Uri` values, not hand-crafted ones like you're proposing. Moreover, the `Uri` itself only needs to be consistent on a device, not across all devices. "the only real way to ensure you have write access is to check for a permission up the tree" -- I fail to see how that has anything to do with "I'd like to go from a file scheme (file://) to a document scheme (content://...externalstorage...)". If you are using SAF, you don't *have* `file://` `Uri` values.

Comment: The uri is not handcrafted at all.  These are all official Android facilitated uris pointing to the same file (and it's root permission).

For non-transient storage there is a corresponding file:// and content://(document) uri for any given entity on storage.  It's a question of can I get the corresponding document uri from a file uri so that the permission can be reliably checked.  And as I mentioned that would require a way to correlate what SAF defines as 0000-0000 (and getName replies sdcard1) and the actual /storage/sdcard1.

Comment: "there is a corresponding file:// and content://(document) uri for any given entity on storage" -- however, the conversion between those is undocumented, unsupported, and subject to change, as I outlined in my original comment. There are thousands of different device models. There could be thousands of different `Uri` structures for this provider, modified on each of those models by the device manufacturer, not to mention changes introduced by custom ROMs or future versions of Android itself. Hence, this is why I wrote that what you want is "certainly is not possible in any reliable fashion".

Comment: Manufacturers are not a concern on this particular issue unless you're concerned with supporting rogues.  It's been required to implement the Google method to pass testing since 4.4.  But it's likely correct there's no reliable way to do it, as there's really nothing reliable about SAF, unless you're willing to to hassle the user for every single file interaction and wait 30s for findFiles to perform its duties.

Comment: "It's been required to implement the Google method to pass testing since 4.4" -- I would be very surprised if the CTS required a particular `Uri` structure and conversion algorithm to/from file paths. I do not see any CTS tests that meet your description. If you know of a CTS test that would prevent a manufacturer from using a `Uri` structure like `content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/9ae066255e3177c2fc83681fd1‌​cb488112a0eb50`, I'd love to see it!

Comment: It would require replacing `ExternalStorageProvider` which would fail testing.  It would also further break `DocumentFile` and especially `DocumentsContract`.

Comment: If you think about it, it would break a fair chunk of the support library to allow a manufacturer that freedom.

Comment: The proposed [document-api] tag is immediately ambiguous, so I've deleted it. If a specific tag is warranted for this API (and I'm not sure it is), avoid creating one that would lead to mis-tagging of irrelevant questions.

Comment: Why is it ambiguous and why would it be unnecessary?  Do you know what the Document API is?  It's impossible to interact with files without it now.

Based on your profile, and I don't mean any offense, it appears you might not have enough background for moderating intimate details on this particular aspect of Android.

What would you propose for a legitimate tag for the growing number of document-api questions on StackOverflow?